# jQuery ajax call with OpenWeatherMap - net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, openweathermap

I want to get weather from OpenWeatherMap API based on latitude and longitude, but I'm getting error

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Project is on codepen.io

```
var appid = "myID";

function getLocation() {
  $.getJSON('https://geoip-db.com/json/geoip.php?jsonp=?') 
        .done (function(location)
        {
          $('.country').html(location.country_name);
          $('.city').html(location.city);
          var lat = location.latitude;
          var lon = location.longitude;
          var weatherLink = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=" + appid + "&callback=?";
          $('body').append(weatherLink);
          $.ajax({
              url: weatherLink,
              dataType: "jsonp",
              success: function(response) {
                  $('body').append(response);
              }
          });  
        });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  getLocation();
});
```

I'm using https://geoip-db.com/ to get latitude and longitude. URL (weatherLink) is correct. Full error:

> GET
>   https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=51.1&lon=17.0333&appid=…0b9873ed&callback=jQuery22406914555127333375_1469796455615&_=1469796455617
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: thats a low level socket error.

Comment: And what can I do about it?

Comment: ask openweathermap, not here.

Comment: Ok then, but maybe I have some other error in code? here is codepen with full code: https://codepen.io/gkopowski/pen/JKBXxa

Answer (score 0):

Your APPid is wrong, just sign up for an account and get a key from the site. You need a valid ID or it will refuse your connection.

http://openweathermap.org/appid#get

link me your codepen and I can take a closer look if you'd like.

Also, if you want to append the information from the site, you need to specify the parameters you want, otherwise your going to get a bunch of nonsense.

Comment: I have valid ID, but I have changed it to "myID" to show my code. Here is codepen https://codepen.io/gkopowski/pen/JKBXxa

Comment: look again, there is an $.ajax call that produces error in console

Comment: try using getJSON instead, I had no problems when I did that challenge haha

Comment: sorry I can't be much more help, I tinkered around a bit but couldn't figure it out, I just thought you made a bonehead mistake with appID haha

Comment: its a little sloppy but here is my codepen if you need a reference,
http://codepen.io/willcodes/pen/bZLWRo