# OpenWeatherMap API HTTPS refusal javascript

Tags: javascript, api, openweathermap

I'm working through free code camp and trying to build a weather app using OpenWeatherMap API but It's not working. I'm using codepen because that's what it needs to be submitted on and it has to be a https to use geo location. This has become a problem because I get this error.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://s.codepen.io/boomerang/8658fc75197c1c3799d7eb446c1be54c1475174843341/index.html?editors=0010' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=54.757753799999996&lon=-1.6074879&APPID=APIIDHERE'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

For some reason I thought it might work if I change the API call to HTTPS but then I get this error

> GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=54.757775699999996&lon=-1.6074815999999998&APPID=APIIDHERE net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have used an api key but i've just hidden it on here.

I've tried a few different ways of fixing it i've seen on other posts but nothing has worked so far :/

I'm using this code for the request

```
function updateLoc (lat, long) {
    var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?" + 
        "lat=" + lat + 
        "&lon=" + long + 
        "&APPID=" + APPID;
    sendRequest (url);
}

function sendRequest (url) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse (xmlhttp.responseText);

            var weather = {};
            weather.icon = data.weather.icon;
            weather.dir = data.wind.deg;
            weather.wind = data.wind.speed;
            weather.temp = data.main.temp;
            weather.loc = data.name;
            weather.hum = data.main.humidity;

            update (weather);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open ("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send ();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I wrote a solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659464/jquery-ajax-call-with-openweathermap-neterr-connection-refused/44900102#44900102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Try using the `https://pro.openweathermap.org` endpoint instead.</strike>

Actually, it seems like the OpenWeatherMap SSL support [isn't free](http://openweathermap.org/price).
You have to either proxy your requests, or use different services.

Comment: That's grim baha, it's the API the course recommends. Cheers

Comment: try using codepen on a regular http connection instead

Comment: It doesn't let me use geo location if I do :/ I could try and find another way of getting coordinates.

Comment: damn... maybe a different browser x.x

Answer (score 2):

If you must make use of HTTPS, append the following to the url of the API
`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` so that it becomes something like this...

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Bamenda&appid=****myid`

use that to make your API calls and they will be treated as secured

Answer (score 0):

It's working now I think it was because it said readystate instead of readyState :/

Answer (score 0):

I have been in exact same situation and here is the answer.

It is because, the page (`https://codepen.io`) is loaded over https, however the request been made to a non-secure source. (`http://openweathermap.org`). So basically it won't serve a non-secure content on a secure page.

You have 2 options;

1. Switch to non-secure codepen page (`http://codepen.io/.....`)
2. Buy PRO membership from openweathermap.org and send requests to https://... channel

Answer (score 0):

I did same and had same problem, when push this to github pages. Problem is removing http to https.
I used fetch method, because it is flexible. Check my code there https://github.com/bondarenko-vlad/weather-js

Answer (score -1):

I faced this same issue. I finally solved it by simply using the unsecured HTTP request, instead of the secured, HTTPS request. ie I changed the api url from `https://api.openweathermap.org/...` to `http://api.openweathermap.org/...`

Here is the supporting code:

**NOT WORKING**

```
function fetchWeatherInfo(){
     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Bamenda&appid=****myid',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {},
            cache: false
        });

}
```

**WORKING**

```
function fetchWeatherInfo(){
     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Bamenda&appid=****myid',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {},
            cache: false
        });

}
```

Comment: This works if your site is HTTP, which is kinda obsolete.

Comment: Not working in my case. Both http and https giving me cors.